# rush does not update dependency in package.json

Tags: pnpm, rush

I have a project which is using rush as a build tool.

`package.json` includes both `dependencies` and `devDependencies` sections.

A package `foo` is referenced in both sections. I want to update `foo` from version 1 to version 2

If I run the command

```
rush add -p foo@2 -m
```

Only the reference in the `devDependencies` section is updated. Same if I run

```
rush add -p foo@2 -m --dev
```

Any suggestion on how to update the package in both sections?
I am using node 20.9.0, pnpm 8.9.1, npm 6.14.15, rush 5.109.2